# What is Hexxit mod in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I have heard about a mod that is (apparently) really fun to use. It's called *Hexxit*.

What is that mod about? What functionality does it add to the game?

Comment: Couldn't you google this? https://www.google.com/search?q=hexxit&oq=hexxit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1266j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Hexxit](http://www.technicpack.net/hexxit) is not a mod, it's a modpack – a collection of mods selected with a theme in mind, preconfigured to work well together, and packaged in an easy-to-install way.

Hexxit's theme is adding fantasy CRPG elements to Minecraft. You can read more and find download instructions on the [Hexxit homepage](http://www.technicpack.net/hexxit).